# Limit associated to a quadratic recurrence

Tags: limits

Let $a_{n}>1$ ,and such $$\begin{cases}
a_{1}=2\\
a^2_{n+1}-a_{n+1}-a^2_{n}+1=0
\end{cases}$$
show that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{n}=1$$

Try $$(a_{n+1}-a_{n})(a_{n+1}+a_{n})=a_{n+1}-1>0$$
and
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n+1}+a_{n}}<1$$
thus we have
$$a_{n}<a_{1}+(n-1)=n+1$$

$a_{n}>?$

Comment: you solved the question $a_n<n+1$ thus $a_n/n<1+1/n$ and $a_n>1$ given thus by sandwich theorem you have your answer

Comment: $a_{n}>1$  $\dfrac{a_{n}}{n}>\dfrac{1}{n}$ then？

Comment: you have this $1<a_n<1+1/n$ now apply sandwich theorem

Comment: That is not enough as you want $ 1 < \dfrac{a_n}{n} < 1+\dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: @avz2611,you must be carefull

Comment: ah i messed up i see

Comment: Note that $(a_{n+1}-\frac12)^2=a_{n+1}^2-a_{n+1}+\frac14=a_n^2-\frac34=\frac14(4a_n^2-3)$ hence $$a_{n+1}=\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{4a_n^2-3}=a_n+\frac12-\frac32\frac1{b_n}$$ with $$b_n=2a_n+\sqrt{4a_n^2-3}.$$ If $a_n\geqslant2$, $b_n\geqslant4+\sqrt{13}\geqslant7$ hence $$a_{n+1}>a_n+\frac12-\frac32\frac17=a_n+\frac27,$$ in particular, for every $a_1\geqslant2$, we know that $a_n\geqslant2$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and that $a_n\to\infty$. Now, $b_n\to\infty$ hence $$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac12+o(1),$$ which in turn implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n=\frac12.$$